# How to fix duplicated checkboxes problem in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on bus booking system and I am trying to pass booked seat detail into blade but I am unable to pass the values

Collect :

```
public function booking(Request $request)
    {
        //river is used to pass important params with flow of it from page to page
        $seat         = $request->seat;
        $buses_id     = $request->buses_id;
        $schedules_id = $request->schedules_id;
        $data         = Buses::where('buses_id', $buses_id)->first();
        $seat         = json_decode($data->seat_layout, true);
        $front        = json_decode($data->front_layout, true);
        $bookingSeat  = Bookings::whereColumn('schedules_id', 'schedules_id')->get();

        $bookingSeat = $bookingSeat->map(function ($bookSeat) {
            $bookSeat->seat = explode(",", $bookSeat->seat);
            return $bookSeat;
        });

        return view('frontend.booking', ['seat' => $seat, 'buses_id' => $buses_id, 'schedules_id' => $schedules_id, 'front' => $front, 'bookingSeet' => $bookingSeat]);

    }
```

blade.php

```
<div class="bus">
@foreach($seat as $key => $item)
@foreach($bookingSeet as $seer)
   <div class="col-md-1">
   <div class="seats back seats 
   @if(in_array($item['name'], $seer['seat']))
   activeSeat
   @endif"
   data-id="{{$key}}">
   <div class="special-attributes"></div>
   @if(isset($item['name'])){{$item['name']}}@else 11A @endif

   <input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" id="{{$key}}" value="{{$key}}">

   </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
@endforeach
</div>
```

Here, I'm using two `froeach` 1st : `@foreach($seat as $key => $item)` 2nd : `@foreach($bookingSeet as $seer)`

Here, 1st one has all the seats which are coming from `bus table`, 49 seats are bound to this.

The 2nd one is booked seats, which are coming from `booking table` then checking with 1st one with then showing all the booked seat in view

booking table :

```
bookings_id users_id schedules_id buses_id routes_id seat price profile
    1           1         6           1       3        1  Null  pending
    2           1         6           1       3        2  Null  booked
    3           1         6           1       3        3  null  booked
```

**Problem :** The problem is when i have a 3 rows in my `booking table` my blade showing seats like this `bus table seats = 49*3 = booking table no of rows` if i have 4 row then 49*4

[image]

bookingseet array

```
Collection {#418 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Bookings {#432 ▶}
    1 => Bookings {#433 ▶}
    2 => Bookings {#434 ▶}
  ]
}
```

bookingseet one array look like this

```
Collection {#418 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => Bookings {#432 ▼
      #fillable: array:7 [▼
        0 => "buses_id"
        1 => "users_id"
        2 => "schedules_id"
        3 => "routes_id"
        4 => "seat"
        5 => "price"
        6 => "profile"
      ]
      #primaryKey: "bookings_id"
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▼
        "bookings_id" => 1
        "users_id" => 1
        "schedules_id" => 6
        "buses_id" => 1
        "routes_id" => 3
        "seat" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "1"
        ]
        "price" => null
        "profile" => "pending"
        "created_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2019-04-09 00:00:00"
      ]
      #original: array:10 [▶]
    }
```

I'm really stuck with this, help me. I really don't know how to describe my problem.

Var_dump :

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#418 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\Bookings)#98 (26) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(7) { [0]=> string(8) "buses_id" [1]=> string(8) "users_id" [2]=> string(12) "schedules_id" [3]=> string(9) "routes_id" [4]=> string(4) "seat" [5]=> string(5) "price" [6]=> string(7) "profile" } ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(11) "bookings_id" ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> NULL ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(10) { ["bookings_id"]=> int(6) ["users_id"]=> int(1) ["schedules_id"]=> int(10) ["buses_id"]=> int(3) ["routes_id"]=> int(7) ["seat"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["price"]=> NULL ["profile"]=> string(7) "pending" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2019-04-23 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-04-23 00:00:00" } ["original":protected]=> array(10) { ["bookings_id"]=> int(6) ["users_id"]=> int(1) ["schedules_id"]=> int(10) ["buses_id"]=> int(3) ["routes_id"]=> int(7) ["seat"]=> string(1) "1" ["price"]=> NULL ["profile"]=> string(7) "pending" ["created_at"]=> string(19) "2019-04-23 00:00:00" ["updated_at"]=> string(19) "2019-04-23 00:00:00" } ["changes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["timestamps"]=> bool(true) ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } } } }
```

Comment: You should loop through foreach loops in your controller and generate an associative array with keys to identify booked seats so that on the blade you will need to loop once while checking only for booked seat. I hope you understood.

Comment: @DineshSuthar sorry sir, I don't understand your answer very well, which foreach loop both?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your second `foreach` was making the duplicated rows.

Try to restrain the second `foreach` where you need it.

```
@foreach($seat as $key => $item)

   <div class="col-md-1">
   <div class="seats back seats 
   @foreach($bookingSeet as $seer)
      @if(in_array($item['name'], $seer['seat']))
      activeSeat
      @endif"
   @endforeach
   data-id="{{$key}}">
   <div class="special-attributes"></div>
   @if(isset($item['name'])){{$item['name']}}@else 11A @endif

   <input type="checkbox" name="seat_id[]" id="{{$key}}" value="{{$key}}">

   </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Tried sir but only one seat showing as booked, 1st one only

Comment: @thush could you post a  `var_dump` of `bookingSeet->toArray()` ?